# Converting selected combobox item to useable string variable

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I'd like to know how I can take an item selected in my combobox, and convert it to a string variable, which I then use to complete my MySQL query. I'm very much a beginner at C# so any help would  be appreciated.

I've tried the following code which I found here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't do the trick. I tried to fill the label1 so I could see if it's working, but I actually need to put it into an mysql query:

```
string selected0
= this.clubComboBox0.GetItemText(this.clubComboBox0.SelectedItem);
            label1.Text = selected0;
```

Comment: So when you select an Item from `clubComboBox0` and run the code, what do you see on `label1.Text`?

Comment: Is this a `ComboBox` in a Windows Form? Have you tried `this.clubComboBox0.SelectedItem.ToString();` instead?

Comment: Actually I tried both `clubComboBox0.GetItemText(this.clubComboBox0.SelectedItem)` and `clubComboBox0.SelectedItem.ToString();` and both works well on `label1.Text`

Comment: When I use this line of code:  teamCombo0.comboboxFiller(teamComboBox0, "select distinct team from teams WHERE Club =" + selected0);   It throws an exception that says (if I select ABCD from the list)  Unknown column 'ABCD' in 'where clause'. Why is it seeing this as a column? When it should be seeing it as an entry IN a column....